# Order lines of text files

Tags: php

I'd like to give an order to be determined with an array to sample files below

```
Carlo>Portiere
Marco>Attaccante
Paolo>Difensore
Antonio>Ala destra
Andrea>Ala sinistra
```

I wish I could change with an array arrangement of the rows of files squadra.txt

```
Carlo>Portiere
 Paolo>Difensore
 Antonio>Ala destra
 Andrea>Ala sinistra
 Marco>Attaccante
```

this and the PHP code I use to view the file squadra.txt

```
    <?php
// setto il file da leggere
$txt = "squadra.txt";
$array = array("Portiere", "Difensore", "Ala destra", "Ala sinistra", "Attaccante");

// leggo rigo per rigo
$righi = file($txt);

// ordino
sort($righi);

// ordino secondo l'array
natsort($array);
echo "\nNatural order sorting\n";
print_r($array);

// visualizziamo
echo '<pre>';
print_r($righi);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

are very inexperienced and until now have only been able to read the file and print to video, I would put an array that can define a natural order, but how does it fit?

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php natsort on the php array.  php arrays --> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: What kind of logic is behind your order?

Comment: I have seen the manual and tried to set the natsort, but I could not figure out how to do, I need to manipulate a set of files where each line is a player and its role, but the files that fit me are in order random and would rearrange them according to the playing role, 
the roles are represented after the symbol ">"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign relative weights to each role and then break your file into lines which can then be split into player and role. Build a new array with the role weight as the key. Sort this array in descending order.

Try this:

```
$weights = array("Portiere"=>100, "Difensore"=>90, "Ala destra"=>80, "Ala sinistra"=>70, "Attaccante"=>60);

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $righi);
foreach($lines as $id => $player){
  list($name, $position) = explode(">", $player);
  $weighted[$weights[trim($position)]] = array('name'=>$name, 'position'=>$position);
}

//sort by keys (reverse order ... descending)
krsort($weighted);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($weighted);
echo '</pre>';
```

---

**EDIT**

My mistake. You are using file(), so $righi is already an array getting each line from the file as an entry.

Change

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $righi);
foreach($lines as $id => $player){
```

To This

```
foreach($righi as $id => $player){
```

Also, if you want to see it come back as a string instead of a detailed array, do this instead of the print_r()

```
foreach($weighted as $player){
  echo implode(">",$player)."<br>";
}
```

**Edit for file output**

This should help you out. It also simplifies some of the $weighted array structure - if you're not using the array elements anywhere else.

```
foreach($righi as $id => $player){
  list($name, $position) = explode(">", $player);
  $weighted[$weights[trim($position)]] = trim($player);
}

//sort by keys (reverse order ... descending)
krsort($weighted);

//output to screen
echo implode("<br>",$weighted);

//overwrite original file
file_put_contents($txt, implode(PHP_EOL, $weighted));
```